# How to div element within another div element using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is sample HTML code :

```
   <div class="cb-col cb-col-25 cb-mtch-blk"><a class="cb-font-12" href="/live-cricket-scores/16947/ind-vs-ban-only-test-bangladesh-tour-of-india-2017" target="_self" title="India v Bangladesh - Only Test">
<div class="cb-hmscg-bat-txt cb-ovr-flo ">
<div class="cb-ovr-flo cb-hmscg-tm-nm">BAN</div>
<div class="cb-ovr-flo" style="display:inline-block; width:140px">322/6 (104.0 Ovs)</div>
</div>
```

I want to extract text like **BAN** and **322/6 (104.0 Ovs)** from the above parsed html. Iam doing like this-

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div_class = soup.findAll('div',class_='cb-col cb-col-25 cb-mtch-blk')
for each in div_class:
    #I want to get those texts from variable 'each'
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [some css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with BeautifulSoup4:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = ...  # the html provided in the question
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> name, size = soup.select('div.cb-hmscg-bat-txt.cb-ovr-flo div')
>>> name.text
u'BAN'
>>> size.text
u'322/6 (104.0 Ovs)'
```

Comment: In line no. 4, I'm getting an error as "Too many values to unpack". What should I do?

Comment: @ddlj, How about this instead of line #4: `print([x.text for x in soup.select('div.cb-hmscg-bat-txt.cb-ovr-flo div')])`

Comment: @ddlj, BTW, could you  share the actual html (or url from where you got the html)? as you can see in my answer, I could get those two texts using the given html in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`each` means the HTML code you provided, you should go to the next `div` tag, and get the all the text use `stripped_strings`.

```
div_class = soup.findAll('div',class_='cb-col cb-col-25 cb-mtch-blk')
for each in div_class:
    name, size = each.div.stripped_strings
    print(name, size)
```

out:

```
BAN 322/6 (104.0 Ovs)
```